# Meaning of the term $1$-complemented

Tags: functional-analysis

If I have a Banach space $E$, and a subspace $F$ of $E$, what does it mean exactly for $F$ to be $1$-complemented in $E$?

A friend suggested that it means there exists a norm $1$ projection $P:E\to F$, which
sounds reasonable to me (and I can't think of another sensible meaning to assign to the $1$).

Could anyone confirm this? or supply the true definition if this isn't it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct. One says that $F$ is $\lambda$-complemented if there is a projection onto $F$ with norm $\le \lambda$. If $\lambda=1$, this is a $1$-complemented subspace.

Example of usage: for every normed space $X$,  the space $X^*$ is $1$-complemented in $X^{***}$.